# How I can automate a process that uploads txt file data from Azure Logic App to on-premise Oracle database?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

This is my monthly routine process:

1. I received a text file from another company.
2. I load the file into the Oracle database by calling sqlldr.exe.
3. Run a couple of store procedures in the Oracle database.
4. Export output of one store procedure to CSV file
   I would like to automate this process by using the Azure Logic App or Azure function, is it possible?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install

Comment: Thanks. I have used the data gateway which I can connect to the Oracle database, however, I would like to automate Step 2 which call sqlldr.exe to load data to oracle

Comment: There are numerous building blocks you can use, a virtual machine for one.  How you trigger that on the virtual machine can be done via multiple means as well, i.e. PowerShell script using Run Commands from Azure, externally exposed web service, internal web service or better yet, a Service Bus listener sitting on a VM that can run your sqlldr.exe command.  You could read the CSV and load it in using a connection to the DB and SQL statements rather than sqlldr.exe ... there are many options.  All of which can be achieved with Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Skin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772095/skin)   for bringing up the Usage of Azure. There are numerous building blocks you can use, a virtual machine. You can trigger that on the virtual machine it can be flexible to use whatever you want.

But in your requirement, you have to use the below steps to achieve this.

I don’t think using **sqlldr.exe** will be complicated while using this module in the azure function and logic app.

So you can use [BCP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/load-from-csv-with-bcp) to achieve this which is the ease of use in azure function to load your file data into the database.

Here you can use the Logic App & Azure function to achieve this.

Create an azure function to do the below tasks

> 1. I received a text file from another company.
> 2. I load the file into the Oracle database by calling sqlldr.exe.

Instead of using **SQLDIR.EXE**, you can use the `BCP`.

Check the reference to [use BCP to load the file into the database](https://bitbucket.org/PrashantPratap/azurefunctionszipbcp/src/master/).

Once done with the above process create the Logic App and include the azure function in the flow.

[image]

Select the Azure Function and add your created azure function.

> 3. Run a couple of store procedures in the Oracle database.
> 4. Export output of one store procedure to CSV file

And next flow you can use the **oracle database** and use action as Execute Stored Procedure and configure your oracle server and run your Stored procedure.

[image]

Refer [here](https://dotnetdevlife.wordpress.com/2016/12/04/bcp-in-azure-functions/) for more information